# How to read 2 different folder which inside have identical subfolder and in it have csv file, compare it and plot into a line chart?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

My current code run into a problem where it just mix up all of the first folder's subfolder csv value into one chart

I have tried to let it read both folder but it seems like only able to read the first root folder only location only...
my expectation is from eq/1st/datasheet/1.csv and qx/2nd/datasheet/1.csv has been read and plot into the line chart to differentiate the mean_pixel_value, and it will continue looping thru "eq/1st/datasheet2/1.csv" and "qx/2nd/datasheet2/1csv" until the end of the subfolder.

*everything inside of the csv file is the same, only the mean_pixel_value is different

```
import os
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root_folder_path_1 = "eg/1st/datasheet/"
root_folder_path_2 = "qx/2nd/datasheet/"

subfolder_names = []
file_names = []
mean_values = []

for subdir_name in os.listdir(root_folder_path_1):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(root_folder_path_1, subdir_name)
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
        subfolder_names.append(subdir_name)

for subdir_name in os.listdir(root_folder_path_2):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(root_folder_path_2, subdir_name)
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):
        subfolder_names.append(subdir_name)

for subdir_name in subfolder_names:
    # Check if sub-folder exists in first destination folder
    subdir_path_1 = os.path.join(root_folder_path_1, subdir_name)
    if os.path.exists(subdir_path_1):
        csv_folder_path = subdir_path_1
    else:
        csv_folder_path = os.path.join(root_folder_path_2, subdir_name)

    csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(csv_folder_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

    for csv_file in csv_files:
        csv_file_path = os.path.join(csv_folder_path, csv_file)

        with open(csv_file_path, mode='r') as file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
            header = next(csv_reader)  # Skip header
            for row in csv_reader:
                file_names.append(row[0])
                mean_values.append(float(row[1]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6)) # Resize the plot to a smaller size
plt.plot(file_names, mean_values, '-o')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right", fontsize=8)
plt.xlabel('File Name', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Mean Pixel Value')
plt.title('Mean Pixel Values for TIFF Images')

save_path = os.path.join(root_folder_path_1, "mean_value.png")
plt.savefig(save_path, bbox_inches="tight")
plt.clf()

print(f"Plots saved in {save_path}")
```